# Calling a float return from method 1 in another method Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, methods

I'm trying to return the value of "totaal" in an `NSLog()` message. If I put all the code in the `- (IBAction)txtChangeEinde:(id)sender` it works fine, I'm just trying to figure out how those methods and classes work.

```
@implementation Oak
@synthesize txtEinde,txtBegin,cboSchaal;

- (float)berekenTotaal:(float) totaal{
  begin = [txtEinde floatValue];
  einde = [txtBegin floatValue];
  if (begin<0) {
    begin= begin*-1;
  }
  totaal = begin + einde;



  return totaal;

}
  - (IBAction)txtChangeEinde:(id)sender {
    //where it goes wrong!
    NSLog(@"totaal: %.2f",[berekenTotaal totaal]);


}
```

[Sample Code (image)](http://tinypic.com/r/2iu6hdv/5)

Comment: Why does the `berekenTotaal` method take a `float` parameter? The value is not used in the implementation of the method.

Comment: @maddy well, i'm wondering if the entire idea of the methods and classes are correct. So if you have some fine-tuning and global line extra's. I'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call like this,

```
- (IBAction)txtChangeEinde:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"totaal: %.2f",[self berekenTotaal:totaal]);   OR

    NSLog(@"totaal: %.2f",[self berekenTotaal:someFloatValue]);


}
```

Comment: Just tried them both, I get the warning:
"use of undeclared identifier 'totaal'"

Comment: @Ben Vertonghen:in the place someFloatValue you can take somefloat value or  define like this       float someFloatValue = 12.5;

Comment: NSLog(@"totaal: %.2f",[self berekenTotaal:0]);

Well, this works but I wonder why?

Comment: once read this one ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591969/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and figure it out, héhé