# How to call default insertNewObject method in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I call the default insertNewObject method? I have created a custom button in the storyboard and linked it to an action called addDate, but I don't quite understand what parameter the insertNewObject takes in

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
if (!_objects) {
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
 [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


- (IBAction)addDate:(id)sender {
// have to call insertNewObject
}
```

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2148655&seqNum=7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a method in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591969/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(id)sender` is a parameter that refers to the `UIView` that is calling the method, normally a `UIButton`
If you don't need any parameters on this function, just delete `:(id)sender` and call

```
[self insertNewObject];
```

if you actually need a parameter, say a NSString, substitute `:(id)sender` for           `:(NSString)parameter` or whatever type of parameter you want, and call

```
[self insertNewObject:yourParameter];
```