# How to convert a milliseconds timestamp to date and time in iOS/XCode?

Tags: ios

I have a timestamp measured in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

eg. input  "takeoffTime": "1396614600000"
    output in date format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert milliseconds to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741199/convert-milliseconds-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by doing the following:

`[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1396614600000/1000];`

This will give you `2014-04-04 12:30:00 +0000`. You should read up on how to pass messages (call methods) here: [How can I call a method in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591969/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

The `NSDate` class gives you this method `+ (instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds`.

Look here: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:)

Comment: judging from the fact that he has no decimal point and has an actual amount of millisecond he additionally needs to divide by `1000.0` because `NSTimeInterval` denotes `seconds`.

Comment: @PankajBhardwaj then read some tutorial please. It has been asked and answered and written out more than a million times how to convert a string to a `int` or `long`. Take a look at the documentation and read about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* takeOffTime = @"1396614600000";
double miliSec = takeOffTime.doubleValue;
NSDate* takeOffDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:miliSec/1000];
```