# how do i convert a string to specific format

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have referred lot of links but could not find the solution hence asking it again.I have string which i need to convert into date format. Below is example

Input string : "1410271500"
In above string 14 is for 2014

```
            10 is for Oct

            27 is day

            1500 is 3:00 PM
```

Output string : "2014-10-27 03:00:00"

Input string in not in long-integer format.

Thanks

Comment: this may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388335/how-to-convert-a-milliseconds-timestamp-to-date-and-time-in-ios-xcode)

Comment: it is not duplicate...plz check it

Comment: @user1291401 - ok I agree, can you show your tried code, what the output you expect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - i already mentioned input and output string. I'm getting this output - "1970-01-17 07:44:31 +0000"

Comment: @user1291401 - can you updated the question, it is easy to optimize

Comment: you can do this in two ways,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - i hv updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
NSString *getMilliSec = @"1410271500";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyMMddHHmm"];
NSDate *getDate = [formatter dateFromString:getMilliSec];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"]; // or use yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; // optional
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:getDate];
```

**swift3**

```
 let getMilliSec = "1410271500"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyMMddHHmm"
    let getDate = formatter.date(from: getMilliSec)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" // or use yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system // optional
    var stringFromDate = formatter.string(from: getDate!)
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: @user1291401 - you need any modification